# Scaling and stacking 2 videos

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 inputs and I want to scale, crop and put them on top of each other at the same time. My command should look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -filter_complex crop=10000:5000:1000:0,scale=3840:1536 vstack output.mp4
```

I know I need to use chaining (?) but I tried to look it up online and couldn't really get it to work.

So what would be the correct syntax the scale and crop both inputs and then put them vertically on top of each other while using '-filter_complex' only once?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to tell each filter which steam to use as the input and label the output from each filter. Join each filter with a comma to make a *filterchain*. Join each filterchain with a semicolon.

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]crop=10000:5000:1000:0,scale=3840:1536[top]; \
 [1:v]crop=10000:5000:1000:0,scale=3840:1536[bottom]; \
 [top][bottom]vstack[v]" -map "[v]" output.mp4
```

If you want to merge the audio from both inputs as well:

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]crop=10000:5000:1000:0,scale=3840:1536[top]; \
 [1:v]crop=10000:5000:1000:0,scale=3840:1536[bottom]; \
 [top][bottom]vstack[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a]amerge[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 output.mp4
```

See [FFmpeg Filters Documentation: Filtergraph Syntax](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-syntax) for more info.

Comment: This helped me to combine 2 images set into a video.
I defined input sources as
ffmpeg -i %*_mask.png -i %*_lit.png -filter_complex ...